# Max of the difference between two arrays in UDF

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I have managed to get the function to work (subtracts one array from another and gives me the max of the differences) with the following code:

```
WorksheetFunction.Max([Sheet1!A1:A5 - Sheet2!A1:A5])
```

However, I really need to be able to refer to the ranges in this way:

```
WorksheetFunction.Max(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5") - Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A5"))
```

I have tried this and it does not work.  Why does one range method work and not the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the `[]` are short hand for Evaluate which will return an array.

So to use Range one would need to explicitly use Evaluate:

```
Application.Evaluate("MAX(" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5").Address(1, 1, 1, 1) & "-" & Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A5").Address(1, 1, 1, 1) & ")")
```

But may be quicker to load the values into variant arrays and then iterate that to find the MAX:

```
Dim Sht1 as variant
Sht1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5").Value

Dim Sht2 as Variant
Sht2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A5").Value

Dim Mx as Double
Mx = -99999999

Dim i as Long
For i = Lbound(Sht1,1) to Ubound(sht1,1)
    If sht1(i,1) - sht2(i,1) > Mx then Mx = sht1(i,1) - sht2(i,1)
Next i

Debug.Print Mx
```

Comment: I tried to use Evaluate and it gave me 'Error 2015' (I copied and pasted your line).  What does that mean?

Comment: @Xenedra sorry had a typo.  But once again I would suggest you use the variant array method, it will be quicker for larger ranges and it is easier to read.